# How to clear the cache of socket_io_client version 2.0.1?

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, webrtc

I have a flutter application that uses the package 'webrtc_flutter_wrapper' for video calling. Within this package, there is the package 'socket_io_client' with version 2.0.1.
I need to clear the cache that is present in the file socket_io_client.dart because it causing problems in video calling. Currently I have a WebRTCMeetingHelper instance which has a Transport instance which has a Socket instance. Is there a way I can clear the cache of the socket instance by accessing it through the webRTCMeetingHelper?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you unsubscribe from events when they are no longer needed, especially when your widget or component is disposed. This can be done using the off method on the Socket instance.

```
// Assuming socket is your Socket instance
socket.off('eventName');
// Disconnect and reconnect
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect();
```

If you encounter issues that seem related to internal state, consider reconnecting the socket or creating a new Socket instance when needed. This can help in situations where the internal state of the socket might be causing unexpected behavior.